# Understanding an Inner Product Equation in the Context of a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider the following snippet taken from *From Fourier Analysis to Wavelets*:

> [image]
>   [image]

Here $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, while $\phi_j$ denotes a complete orthonormal basis over some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Also, $R$ denotes a representation operator from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to $l^2$ (square summable sequences).

**Question 1:** What justifies the first equational reasoning?

**Question 2:** What justifies the move from $\mid \mid F f \mid \mid^2 = \langle F^* F f, f \rangle$?

Comment: In a Hilbert space $\| T f\|^2 = \langle T f,T f \rangle=\langle T^*T f, f \rangle$

Comment: Why does $\langle Tf, Tf \rangle = \langle T^*T f, f \rangle$? Is that a separate lemma?

Comment: That's the definition of $T^*$ the adjoint operator : $\langle u,Tv \rangle =\langle T^*u,v \rangle$ which [always exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_bounded_operators_between_Hilbert_spaces) if $T$ is bounded and exists only on a dense subset if $T$ is unbounded. On finite dimensional vector spaces (so that $T$ is a matrix $M$) then $M^* = \overline{M^\top}$. And $M^* M$ is a positive semi-definite matrix so the spectral theorem applies (ie.the  SVD of $M^*M$ is its diagonalization). $M$ is orthonormal means $M^* = M^{-1}$.

Comment: @reuns: What about the first equality? Why does $\langle u , Ru \rangle = \sum u_j \langle \phi_j, f \rangle$?